# Rewrite a UNION view as a dynamic view

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, view, union

I've been working on this for days and I can't find a proper solution, I'm hoping someone can help.

We have several database servers (SQL Server) with identical structures, connected by linked servers.  We have a bunch of views that union data across all the servers:

```
CREATE VIEW Things_view AS
  SELECT id, thing
    FROM server1.database1.dbo.stuff
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, thing
    FROM server2.database2.dbo.stuff
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, thing
    FROM server3.database3.dbo.stuff
```

There are several problems with this:

- When we add servers, we have to modify
  views.
- Our development environments need
  the same number of databases and fake linked
  servers so we can install these
  views.
- Some of the servers *do not
  include* data from some of the other servers.  Today we do this with customized views on those servers but that's a deployment nightmare.

So I was hoping to rewrite this dynamically.  The goals are:

- Allow development environments to
  contain a different number of databases.  They are likely to
  have 2 or more databases on a single server.
- Provide a way for each server to
  specify which other servers to
  include in the results.
- Minimize the complexity so the
  solution remains somewhat
  maintainable.
- Create one solution that can be
  source controlled and used on all
  servers.

And most importantly:

- **Expose it as a view with the same
  name so we don't have to rewrite our
  entire application.**

Of course, I can't do dynamic SQL in a view or function.  I tried rewriting this as a stored procedure, then using the [OPENROWSET trick](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2005/08/01/408502.aspx) to query the stored proc from a view.  That didn't work because I had to fully qualify the proc with the database name, which would require more dynamic SQL (because the database names are different).  Then I thought about fooling around with synonyms on the master database but that violates the maintenance and source control goals.

I'm perfectly OK with creating a new table with server names and database names and inclusion flags if needed.  In fact, that is ideal because it centralizes the configuration for each environment.

I've been completely baffled by this and now I'm reaching out to you, Internet, in a last-ditch plea for help!

Comment: Do you need to use views? Stored procs possible?

Comment: A stored proc would be fine, as long as it's ultimately exposed to the application as a view with the same name.

Comment: How often do you plan on your number/ name of servers changing?  Does the data have to be real time?

Comment: The number of servers changes infrequently on the shared environments, but we would need this updated immediately when a new server is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Synonym** would be a good option if you are using latest SQL server

Comment: We have a mix of 2005 and 2008 servers.  I thought about creating Synonyms for the views on the master database to make the OPENROWSET trick work, but then I'd need to maintain dozens of synonyms (one for each view), and working outside our application's database is a level of complexity that I'm not sure I'd like to introduce.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to create a stored procedure that adjusts the view.  For example (not tested):

```
create procedure dbo.RecreateView
as
declare @sql varchar(max)

select @sql = IsNull(@sql + 'union all ','') +
              'select * from ' + name + '.dbo.YourView '
from   sys.databases
where  name like 'DbNamePrefix%'

set @sql = 'create view dbo.YourView as ' + @sql
exec (@sql)
```

You could then call the stored procedure after you add a database, or even from a scheduled task.

Comment: I considered this but it messes with our source control; we're using Redgate SQL Source Control.  Every time the view is rebuilt it shows as modified to the source control system, there doesn't seem to be a way to ignore it.  It would be too easy to accidentally deploy an undesirably-modified view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table keeping track of servers and databases you could build the view dynamically in a trigger on that table.

Look at this answer to another question. It suggests the same thing and has some sample code to alter a view definition in a trigger.

[Dynamic table design (common lookup table), need a nice query to get the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669369/dynamic-table-design-common-lookup-table-need-a-nice-query-to-get-the-values/4767474#4767474)

It might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a data warehouse... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse   You would need this to run at a set schedule so the data would not be realtime.  That is the only downside.

Load data from each `server[n].database.tablename` using a file similar to the one below.

```
--Here is how you would administer the script.  One single script that you would only need to modify when you added/removed servers.
So you can easily add this to source control or whatever. You can also do all this, without linked servers, if you look at some ETL tools. like SSIS

insert into dataserver1.datawarehouse.tablename select *,'svr1,'db','tablename' from svr1.db.tablename
insert into dataserver1.datawarehouse.tablename select *,'svr2,'db','tablename' from svr1.db.tablename
insert into dataserver1.datawarehouse.tablename select *,'svr3,'db','tablename' from svr1.db.tablename
insert into dataserver1.datawarehouse.tablename select *,'svr4,'db','tablename' from svr1.db.tablename
insert into dataserver1.datawarehouse.tablename select *,'svr5,'db','tablename' from svr1.db.tablename
insert into dataserver1.datawarehouse.tablename select *,'svr6,'db','tablename' from svr1.db.tablename
insert into dataserver1.datawarehouse.tablename select *,'svr7,'db','tablename' from svr1.db.tablename
insert into dataserver1.datawarehouse.tablename select *,'svr8,'db','tablename' from svr1.db.tablename
```

So you are required to create many insert statements.  One for each server/db/table combo you have.

`insert into dataserver1.datawarehouse.tablename select *,'svr1,'db','tablename' from svr1.db.tablename`

So as you load the data into this new database table, you will simply append to every row the original servername/databasename/tablename SO.... Your data looks like this

```
col1 col2 col3 srvnam dbname tbl
foo  bar  some MSSQL1 master mycooltable
foo  bar  some MSSQL2 other  mycooltable
```

Now, all you have to do is query off of one table,  it will be really fast, and clean.

Comment: Since you CANNOT rename the view, you would finally select * from the above as the script code to create your prexisting view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'd suggest. Create a table to store the configuration for each view on the particular server. 
Then write dynamic sql to create the view script based on those configurations. 
Then run the view script on the server. 
When you want to add a new server, add it to the configurationtable which could have a trigger to automatically recreate the scripts for the views that are being changed. Or have recreating scripts from the table and running them be a standard part of every deployment.